# Specify dynamic subdomain in API Gateway integration request

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway, aws-api-gateway

I would like to specify a dynamic subdomain in an Integration Request in API Gateway, but the UI is telling me that the URL is malformed.  I can add this parameter to the path of the URL with no problems (although I still get the warning "the endpoint you have entered contains parameters that are not defined in the resource path").  Is this mapping to subdomain possible using API Gateway, or do I need a lambda to accomplish this?  Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work, so I assume it's not supported.  I ended up making a different Gateway for each subdomain (I only have a few) and using a lambda to switch between them.  You could also use a lambda without a a Gateway if you have many different subdomains.